# Not getting the API testing sampler in jmeter 3.2

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter version 3.2 for REST API testing but i am not getting the API test request sampler in this version. Anyone who is working on the same version please let me know the option. Currently i am test the API through HTTP request sampler.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not getting the API test request sampler in this version " ? Can you show in View Results Tree what you get ? and also give access to jmeter.log and finally show you HTTP Request config ?

Comment: There's Test Action Sampler which should work, what not working exactly?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `API test request`? You should be able to test either SOAP or REST API endpoints using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you will just need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header, in your case it will most likely be [application/json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

References:

- [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)